# Dynamic route path in form action based on the selected option in Laravel

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form like this in laravel 5.4 view:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <select id="tdcategory" class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                  @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <select id="tdlocation" class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                @foreach($locations as $location)
                    <option value="{{ $location->id }}">{{ $location->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            </div>
</form>
```

I have two questions:

1) How can I dynamically set the form action to something like

> categories/{category->id}/locations/{location->id}

Where, both category->id and location->id will be based on the value of the option the user has currently selected

2) Since the form gets submitted as the user changes the option, the page is then reloaded and resets both of the `<select>` tag. How do I keep track of previously selected option and as the page loads, I can show the user which one did he/she select before the form was submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can do this by JS: remove "onchange" attributes from selects, and add inital code, something like this:

```
$('#tdcategory,#tdlocation').change(function(){
    var category = $('#tdcategory').val();
    var location = $('#tdlocation').val();

    if (category && location) {
        $(this).closest('form')
            .attr('action', '/categories/'+ category +'/locations/' + location)
            .submit();
    }
});
```

2) You can get the submitted value from the request and add a condition for the inserting selected="selected" attribute into every select, something like this:

```
<select id="tdcategory" name="tdcategory" class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" @if($category->id == request()->get('tdcategory'))selected="selected"@endif>{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select id="tdlocation" name="tdlocation" class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow">
    @foreach($locations as $location)
        <option value="{{ $location->id }}" @if($location->id == request()->get('tdlocation'))selected="selected"@endif>{{ $location->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```